# Non-unique Elements

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am doing an exercise on checkio about writing a function to exclude the unique elements in a `list`, and only keep the **non-unique ones**. I wrote the following lines.

```py
    def checkio(data):    
        for i in data:
            if data.count(i) == 1:
                data.remove(i)       
        return data
```

And then did the following tests.

```py
    checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3]) == [1, 3, 1, 3]
    checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == []
    checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
    checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

But the **second test** won't pass. 
Instead of returning an empty array `[]`, it returns `[2,4]`.
Why is that?
Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the code traps it self. The problem is that the `for in data:...` takes the `data[0]` (the first item) of your list. `1` is unique, so your program removes the 1 from your `data` list. `data` is now: `[2,3,4,5]`. Now the for-in loop goes on with `data[1]` which is now the number `3`. `3` is also unique so it removes it. Your list is now: `data = [2,4,5]`. Now your code goes on with `data[2]`, which is `5`. It's removed. At the end there is `data = [2,4]` left. Try to find another solution for your problem. Hope I could help you.

**Edit:**
You shouldn't remove the items from the list. Try to create a new list where you put all non-unique items in it. Try to use "smaller than" and "bigger than" relations (`<,>`).

Answer (score 3):

**Solution**:

```py
def checkio(data):
        duplicates = []
        for i in data:
                if data.count(i) > 1:
                    duplicates.append(i)
        return duplicates
```

Here, as mentioned by [@sp4c38](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12373144/sp4c38) instead of removing the **unique elements** and modifying the original list, add the duplicates to a new `list`.

This passes all the **test-cases**:

```py
checkio([1, 2, 3, 1, 3])
checkio([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]) == []
checkio([5, 5, 5, 5, 5]) == [5, 5, 5, 5, 5]
checkio([10, 9, 10, 10, 9, 8]) == [10, 9, 10, 10, 9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can accomplish that using a single liner

```
def checkio(data):
    return [x for x in data if data.count(x) > 1]
```